# MS Access - Pass login info between forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

Based on this example (http://accesshosting.com/create-login-form-ms-access) I created a login page, but I need help passing the UserLogin from one page to another. Here's the code for validation on login form:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim User As String
Dim UserLevel As Integer
Dim TempPass As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim Username As String
Dim TempID As String

If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Then
 MsgBox "Please enter UserName", vbInformation, "Username required"
 Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
 MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password required"
 Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
 If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "Users", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "' And UserPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
 MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!"
 Else
 TempID = Me.txtUserName.Value

 'Added line for saving the userLogin as global variable
     PassUserData.fillUsername (TempID)

 Username = DLookup("[UserName]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 TempPass = DLookup("[UserPassword]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 UserLogin = DLookup("[UserLogin]", "Users", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
 DoCmd.Close
 If (TempPass = "password") Then
 MsgBox "Please change Password", vbInformation, "New password required"
 DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserinfo", , , "[UserLogin] = " & UserLogin
 Else
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStart"   
 End If
 End If
End If
End Sub
```

I need to open the form 'frmStart' with filtered records based on the UserLogin.
What I did, I created a module (PassUserData) with a global variable, but when I click on command button with some user credentials, table Users - first row (field UserLogin) gets updated with the current userLogin (txtUserName).

```
'Module PassUserData
Option Compare Database
Global G_Username As String

Public Function fillUsername(txtUser As String)
 G_Username = txtUser
End Function

Public Function returnUsername() As String
returnUsername = G_Username
End Function
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably made your login form **bound** to the Users table.

Remove the form's `record source` to make the form unbound, so it won't update any table.

Additional hints:

- Using user input directly in concatenated SQL can lead to errors and SQL injection. Try entering `u'ser`.
- Storing passwords as plain text is bad.
- If you need several values from a table, it is more efficient (and less clunky code) to open a recordset instead of multiple `DLookup()` calls.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm gonna change the password to binary and won't using user, I just wanted to see the example working first :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `PassUserData.fillUsername (TempID)`

And use `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStart", , , , , , TempID`

---

**OpenArgs** argument of the DoCmd.OpenForm method helps to pass any info between forms. Alternatively, you can also store any info in TempVars.

[image]